Add XML namespaces to XPath transforms
I'm trying to sign an Xml file using the SignedXml calls in .Net 8. I'm having an issue with the XPath transforms.
Calling SignedXml.ComputeSignature() throws the following exception:
Unhandled exception. System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace prefix 'ext' is not defined.
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.UndefinedXsltContext.LookupNamespace(String prefix)
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.BaseAxisQuery.SetXsltContext(XsltContext context)
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.SetContext(IXmlNamespaceResolver nsResolver)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigXPathTransform.GetOutput()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.TransformChain.TransformToOctetStream(Object inputObject, XmlResolver resolver, String baseUri)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.CalculateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.UpdateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.BuildDigestedReferences()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.ComputeSignature()

The XPath transforms look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"
                    xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"
                    xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
                    <sac:SignatureInformation>
                        <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                        <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                                <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                         </ds:Transform>
                                         <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                         </ds:Transform>
                                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                     </ds:Transforms>
                                     <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                     <ds:DigestValue>f+0WCqnPkInI+eL9G3LAry12fTPf+toC9UX07F4fI+s=</ds:DigestValue>
                               </ds:Reference>

I thought the class would be smart enough to get the namespaces specified in the XPath expressions automatically, but it seems not. How do I add the namespaces so that the XPath transforms work correctly?

"get the namespaces specified in the XPath expressions automatically" automatically from where? You'd need to define them in the XPath <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="" xmlns:ext="someNamespaceHere" xmlns:cac="someNamespaceHere">

I was expecting it to see the namespaces already declared in the Xml document I want to sign. I've added some more of the Xml document in my question to show the namespaces the XPath expressions are referring to.

Personally I think you are right to expect that when the XPath interpreter evaluates the XPath expression in a ds:XPath element, that the namespace bindings available to the XPath expression should be precisely those in scope for the ds:XPath element that contains the XPath expression. So it's a puzzle to me too.
But you could avoid the issue of namespace prefix bindings by not using namespace prefixes in your XPath, by e.g. replacing a reference to ext:UBLExtensions with this substitute expression:
*
[local-name()='UBLExtensions']
[namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2'

It's a hack, I know, but it might at least get you past this point.
